# bash tool to search and replace text (while leaving text in the middle the same)

Tags: regex, bash

I have text files that look like this:

`foo(bar(some_id))` I want to replace that with
`bleh(some_id)`

I can come up with the regex to find the instances, which is: `foo\(bar\([a-zA-z0-9_]+\)\)`. But I dont know how to express that I want to keep the text in the middle the same.

Any suggestion? (I'm thinking of using `sed` or `awk` or any standard bash tool, whichever is easier )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/foo\(bar\(([^()]*).*/bleh(\1)/'
sed 's/foo(bar(\([^()]*\).*/bleh(\1)/'
```

The first pattern is POSIX ERE compliant, hence the `-E` option.

The `foo\(bar\(([^()]*).*` POSIX ERE pattern matches `foo(bar(`, then captures  any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` into Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value from the replacement pattern), and then matches the rest of string. After the replacement, the Group 1 value remains. You may add `.*` at the start if there is text before `foo(bar(`.

The  second sed command is POSIX BRE equivalent of the above command.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/hDbdVt):

```sh
s='foo(bar(some_id))'
sed -E 's/foo\(bar\(([^()]*).*/bleh(\1)/' <<< "$s"
# => bleh(some_id)
sed 's/foo(bar(\([^()]*\).*/bleh(\1)/' <<< "$s"
# => bleh(some_id)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! ` echo "foo(bar(some_id))abc" | sed -E 's/foo\(bar\(([^()]*).*/bleh\(\1\)/' ` (seems the second option worked for me!)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.*\(([^)]*)\).*/bleh\1/' input_file
bleh(some_id)
```